prove that P is the centroid of the triangle ABC.
The problem
Let the triangle ABC and the points $A′ ∈ (BC), B′ ∈ (CA)$
and $C
′ ∈ (AB)$ be given, such that the lines $AA′
, BB′$
and $CC′$
are concurrent in P.
If $max\{\ \frac{A'P}{AA'}, \frac{B'P}{BB'}, \frac{C'P}{CC'}\}=\frac{1}{3}$
, prove that P is the centroid of the triangle ABC.
The idea

WLOG, we suppose that $\frac{A'P}{AA'}=2$
By van Aubel theorem and the fact that $max \{ \frac{A'P}{AA'}, \frac{B'P}{BB'}, \frac{C'P}{CC'} \}= \frac{1}{3}$ we can say that $2=\frac{AC'}{C'B}+ \frac{AB'}{B'C}, 2 \geq \frac{BC'}{C'A}+ \frac{A'B}{A'C}, 2 \geq \frac{B'C}{AB'}+ \frac{A'C}{BA'}$
Also we can apply ceva's there that says $\frac{AC'}{C'B}* \frac{A'B}{A'C} * \frac{B'C}{AB'}=1$.
Maybe a solution without locus might help :)
I hope one of you can help me, cause I don't know what to do forward!

Can you prove that A', B' and C' are the midpoints of their respective segments?  It's a fact that the centroid of a triangle is the intersection of its medians and a median is the segment from the vertex of a triangle to the midpoint of the side across from it.

$P$ will be the centroid of $∆ABC$ if and only if:
$$\dfrac{AP}{A'P} = \dfrac{BP}{B'P} = \dfrac{CP}{C'P} = 2$$
The "max" expression distorts this idea.

@John Nope, idk how to prove this...i think

Here is a proof using the area of a triangle and ratios chasing. This is @ImbalanceDream proof but in simpler terms.

Theorem 1. $\dfrac{PA'}{AA'} + \dfrac{PB'}{BB'} + \dfrac{PC'}{CC'} = 1$.

Proof of Theorem 1.
\begin{align*}
  \dfrac{PA'}{AA'} = \dfrac{\operatorname{area}(BPA')}{\operatorname{area}(BAA')} \quad\text{and}\quad \dfrac{PA'}{AA'} = \dfrac{\operatorname{area}(CPA')}{\operatorname{area}(CAA')}
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{PA'}{AA'} = \dfrac{\operatorname{area}(BPA') + \operatorname{area}(CPA')}{\operatorname{area}(BAA') + \operatorname{area}(CAA')} = \dfrac{\operatorname{area}(PBC)}{\operatorname{area}(ABC)}.
\end{align*}
Analogously $\dfrac{PB'}{BB'} = \dfrac{\operatorname{area}(PCA)}{\operatorname{area}(ABC)}$ and $\dfrac{PC'}{CC'} = \dfrac{\operatorname{area}(PAB)}{\operatorname{area}(ABC)}$, so $\dfrac{PA'}{AA'} + \dfrac{PB'}{BB'} + \dfrac{PC'}{CC'} = 1$.
End of proof for Theorem 1.
Back to the problem.
Since $\max\left\{ \dfrac{PA'}{AA'}, \dfrac{PB'}{BB'}, \dfrac{PC'}{CC'} \right\} = \dfrac{1}{3}$ and $\dfrac{PA'}{AA'} + \dfrac{PB'}{BB'} + \dfrac{PC'}{CC'} = 1$, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
  \dfrac{PA'}{AA'} = \dfrac{PB'}{BB'} = \dfrac{PC'}{CC'} = \dfrac{1}{3}.
\end{align*}
It follows from the above proof of Theorem 1 and $\dfrac{PA'}{AA'} = \dfrac{PB'}{BB'} = \dfrac{PC'}{CC'}$ that
\begin{align*}
  \operatorname{area}(PBC) = \operatorname{area}(PCA) = \operatorname{area}(PAB).
\end{align*}
Because $\dfrac{A'B}{A'C} = \dfrac{\operatorname{area}(AA'B)}{\operatorname{area}(AA'C)}$ and $\dfrac{A'B}{A'C} = \dfrac{\operatorname{area}(PA'B)}{\operatorname{area}(PA'C)}$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
  \frac{A'B}{A'C} = \frac{\operatorname{area}(AA'B) - \operatorname{area}(PA'B)}{\operatorname{area}(AA'C) - \operatorname{area}(PA'C)} = \frac{\operatorname{area}(PAB)}{\operatorname{area}(PAC)} = 1
\end{align*}
which means $A'$ is the midpoint of line segment $BC$. Similarly, $B', C'$ are the midpoints of line segments $CA, AB$. Hence $P$ is the centroid of triangle $ABC$.
Q.E.D.

We may suppose that
$$\frac{A'P}{AA'}=\frac 13,\ \frac{B'P}{BB'}\le\frac 13,\ \frac{C'P}{CC'}\le\frac{1}{3}$$
Then, we have $\frac{A'P}{PA}=\frac 12, \frac{B'P}{PB}\le \frac 12$ and $\frac{C'P}{PC}\le\frac 12$.
Let $p:=\frac{A'B}{CB},q:=\frac{B'C}{AC}$ and $r:=\frac{C'A}{BA}$ where $0\lt p\lt 1,0\lt q\lt 1$ and $0\lt r\lt 1$.
Now, let us use Menelaus's theorem.

line $BPB'$ passes inside $\triangle AA'C$ : $$\frac{CB}{BA'}\times \frac{A'P}{PA}\times\frac{AB'}{B'C}=1$$i.e. $\frac 1p\times\frac 12\times\frac{1-q}{q}=1$ which implies $q=\frac{1}{2p+1}$.

line $CPC'$ passes inside $\triangle AA'B$ : $$\frac{BC}{CA'}\times\frac{A'P}{PA}\times\frac{AC'}{C'B}=1$$ i.e. $\frac{1}{1-p}\times\frac 12\times\frac{r}{1-r}=1$ which implies $r=\frac{2-2p}{3-2p}$.

line $APA'$ passes inside $\triangle CBB'$ : $$\frac{CA}{AB'}\times\frac{B'P}{PB}\times\frac{BA'}{A'C}=1$$ i.e. $\frac 1{1-q}\times\frac{B'P}{PB}\times\frac{p}{1-p}=1$. So, we have $(\frac{B'P}{PB}=)\frac{(1-p)(1-q)}{p}\le\frac 12$. Solving $\frac{(1-p)(1-\frac{1}{2p+1})}{p}\le\frac 12$ gives $p\ge\frac 12$.

line $APA'$ passes inside $\triangle CC'B$ : $$\frac{BA}{AC'}\times\frac{C'P}{PC}\times\frac{CA'}{A'B}=1$$ i.e. $\frac 1r\times\frac{C'P}{PC}\times\frac{1-p}{p}=1$. So, we have $(\frac{C'P}{PC}=)\frac{pr}{1-p}\le\frac 12$. Solving $\frac{p\times \frac{2-2p}{3-2p}}{1-p}\le\frac 12$ gives $p\le\frac 12$.


Since we have $p\ge\frac 12$ and $p\le\frac 12$, we get $p=\frac 12$ and $q=r=\frac 12$.
We see that $A',B',C'$ is the midpoint of $BC,CA,AB$ respectively, so we can say that $P$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$.

Here is a simple proof.
It is enough to show that the Cartesian  coordinates of $P$ are the means of the coordinates of $A,B,C$. We can assume $P=\alpha_1 A+\alpha_2B+\alpha_3C$ where the nonnegative $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ are the weights with $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=1$.
What we have known is $\max\left\{\frac{A'P}{AA'}, \frac{B'P}{BB'}, \frac{C'P}{CC'}\right\}=\frac{1}{3}$, or $\max\left\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\right\}=\frac{1}{3}$. Therefore $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3\leqslant\frac13+\frac13+\frac13=1$. By assumption the equality holds, so $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=\frac13$.
Now $P=\frac13A+\frac13B+\frac13C$, indicating $P$ is the centroid of triangle $ABC$.

Assume $P$ is not the centroid of $\triangle ABC$ (In the diagram it is). Without loss of generality, assume $max\{\frac{A'P}{AA'}, \frac{B'P}{BB'}, \frac{C'P}{CC'}\} = \frac{A'P}{AA'} = \frac13$. Let $A_P$ be the locus of all points $Q$ that satisfy $\frac{RQ}{AR} = \frac13$ with $R$ being an arbitrary point on line $BC$. Similarly, let $B_P$ be the locus of all points $Q$ that satisfy $\frac{RQ}{BR} = \frac13$ with $R$ being an arbitrary point on line $AC$. Define $C_P$ in the same way. By Intercept Theorem, $A_P||BC$, $B_P||AC$, and $C_P||AB$.
$\mathit{Lemma.}$ Assume a locus $D_P$ of the same kind as $A_P, B_P, C_P$ in $\triangle DEF$. Define a point $D'$ in the same way as in $\triangle ABC$. If an arbitrary point $Q'$ not lying on $D_P$ is on the same side of $D_P$ as $D$, then $\frac{D'Q'}{DD'} > 1/3$. Similarly, if $Q'$ is on the same side of $D_P$ as $EF$, then$\frac{D'Q'}{DD'} < 1/3. $
$\mathit{Proof. }$ The proof is obvious. If you do not understand, I can reply in the comments.
By assumption, $\frac{B'P}{BB'}, \frac{C'P}{CC'} < 1/3$. By the lemma, $P$ lies in $(\triangle C(C_P\cap AC)(C_P\cap BC))\cap(\triangle B(B_P\cap AB)(B_P\cap BC))$. However, P also lies on $A_P$. Hence, P lies in the intersection between $A_P$ and said area. We know that the vertex of that defined area is $B_P \cap C_P$, which lies on $A_P$. Thus, the only possibility is that $P$ lies on the intersection between all three loci $A_P, B_P, C_P$. This implies that $P$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$, which contradicts our first assumption. Hence, $P$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$.
Q. E. D.


Thanks so much for your answer!Is there any way to explain this solution without locus...I didn't learn about them yet

Essentially, think of $A_P$ as all points tat satisfy the 1:2 ratio like point $P$. If you still don't understand, I can rewrite the solution.

I'm soo sorry, but its hard for me to understand :(
